# What are the differences between RunKeeper and Cardio Trainer?

Tags: exercise-equipment, app

I've always used [RunKeeper](http://runkeeper.com/home) to track my runs, but recently I came across an app called [Cardio Trainer](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/cardiotrainer/about.php) (from WorkSmart Labs), and it seems like it does pretty much the same thing. Both apps use GPS to track your outdoor activities, both allow you to share your workouts with your Facebook/Twitter followers and with other users, both integrate with your playlists, etc. Are there any pros/cons to using one over the other?

Comment: I'm sure in most cases they are interchangeable.  There a number of apps that overlap each other, but the user interface is different.  One may suit your tastes better than another.  If RunKeeper works well for you, there is probably little reason to try something else.

Comment: when u start an activity, in CT you can choose what kind of workout you are going to do, there are tens of sports available. My favourite is "Scuba diving", i took phone on a dive with me (i dive in dry suit), but the GPS did not work under water, so the "workout" was not calculated correctly. (What a surprise! :-) Seriously, for accurate calories measurment, u need to enter your weight correctly. u know, this is an Android app, always some setup menus to have fun with :-) i really reccomend to hit Setting button on the main screen and to set up the app according your actual situation.

Answer (score 2):

I use Cardiotrainer more often since it doesn't have to wait till the GPS picks up before recording.  It has a pedometer built in so it estimates the steps/distance etc from that and also allows for exercises such as Stair climbing (which I do in the office when it's rainy and I just want to do some exercise).  The web interface on Runkeeper is a lot better though.  So I just export the GPX files I want to from the CardioTrainer website and upload it to the Runkeeper site.  I haven't used the Runkeeper app for ages.

If only the two had a widget which I could install to synchronise them!  Or consolidate it all into one website so I have the data in one place.

Answer (score 1):

RunKeeper makes tracking your workouts fun, social, and easy to understand so that you can improve the quality of your fitness.
CardioTrainer is a free application for Android smartphones that lets you track and record all of your fitness activity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is CardioTrainer less social than RunKeeper? And when you say "all of your fitness activity" - does that mean you can track more than just distance workouts that you log with a GPS?

Comment: Yes, you can, to some extent, track other pysical activities.